# Fill parent container and reduce image resolution with next/image

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to fill a fixed-size container with an image. `layout="fill"` works like a charm, but even though container is only `125x125`, the original image gets downloaded that has a resolution much higher than that and hence weights much more. I'm able to get reduced resolution with `layout="fixed"`, but I lose the "fill" behaviour this way.

Is there a way to take the best of those 2 worlds with `next/image` - **fill parent container, and at the same time reduce the size of files downloaded to client device**?

Comment: use `srcset` to load the image based on device size.

Comment: @AG_ the size of the image to render does not depend on the screen size. Moreover, Next/Image does not pass the srcSet attrbute to the underlying <img> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the [`deviceSizes`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#device-sizes) property in `next.config.js` to match the breakpoints used in your app, as those are used to generate the `next/image`'s `srcset`s, and serve the correctly sized image.

> If you know the expected device widths of your users, you can specify
> a list of device width breakpoints using the `deviceSizes` property in
> `next.config.js`. These widths are used when the `next/image` component
> uses `layout="responsive"` or `layout="fill"` to ensure the correct image
> is served for user's device.

The above should be paired with the [`sizes`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#sizes) attribute on the `next/image` if the rendered image takes up less than the full viewport width.

> If you are using `layout="fill"`, `layout="responsive"`, or `layout="raw"`
> it's important to assign `sizes` for any image that takes up less than
> the full viewport width.
>
> For example, when the parent element will constrain the image to
> always be less than half the viewport width, use `sizes="50vw"`. Without
> `sizes`, the image will be sent at twice the necessary resolution,
> decreasing performance.

---

As an example, let's assume your app uses the following device breakpoints `[320, 640, 1024, 1280, 1920]`, and you're rendering a `240x240` image.

Update the `deviceSizes` property to match the breakpoints:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        deviceSizes: [320, 640, 1024, 1280, 1920],
        // Other existing `images` configs
    },
    // Other existing configs
}
```

Then set the `sizes` property on the `next/image` to suggest the ideal image size.

```js
<div style={{ position: 'relative', width: 240, height: 240 }}>
    <Image
        src="<image-url>"
        layout="fill"
        sizes="50vw"
    />
</div>
```

You should adjust the above values to better fit your use case.