# NextJS Image component not resizing remote images

Tags: next.js

It was my understanding that the Image component optimizes, resizes and caches images, but when I view the image it is always the full sized version. I have tried all the layout properties - mostly trying to work with responsive, or fill. Maybe I have misunderstood what this component is supposed to do, or maybe I am missing something.

```
<Image
 src={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_URL + product.image.url}
 width={500}
 height={500}
 layout="responsive"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Fill parent container and reduce image resolution with next/image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138976/fill-parent-container-and-reduce-image-resolution-with-next-image)?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.
I commented out the `layout == "responsive"` line and then it scaled appropriately.